# how to create password protected pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am new to ASP.Net and  currently developing a small website in ASP.Net where I am supposed to create a page for uploading the items in a database. I can do that but I am facing a problem like I want that a person with a username and password  stored in database be only able to access that page.
I try to create a login page and after typing the username and password then only the person is able to go to uploaditems.aspx page. But if i type the url of that page in the address bar it does not redirect the user to the login page.
Please tell me how to do that.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should configure your web config file like the code below

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms forms="Frmname" loginUrl="/login.aspx" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```